# Jira, помогите задать условия для отображения задач в дорожке

Tags: jira

В столбце Done накопилось много выполненных задач.

Пришла идея отображать в основной дорожке только 30 последних выполненных задач, а остальные сворачивать в отдельную дорожку. Помогите написать условие для отображение задач в дорожке. Или есть другие способы решения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

написал вот так:

status = Closed OR status = Verified  AND updated < startOfDay("-30d")

как это выглядит, в приложенном скриншоте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]